# How can I filter the Adapter Arraylist on background thread using coroutines?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines

In my Fragment I'm using a Recycler View with multiple item types where i want to filter my parent array list based on some conditions and transfer the filtered list to child recycler view. I am able to filter parent list on main thread but i am worried if the parent array list has thousands of data and performing filtration  on main thread might be not good. So i want to filter my array list on background thread using coroutines. This is how i tried to filter my parent list on background thread using coroutines.

**MainFragmentAdapter**

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
  when (position) {
    1 -> {
            val goldAdapter = GoldAdapter()
             var filterGold = methodCallBack.filterData(gold,"gold")
             if (filterGold.isNotEmpty())
             goldAdapter.goldList = filterGold
             if (mRate.isNotEmpty())
             goldAdapter.goldRate = mRate[0].value!!
            holder.itemView.diamond_text.text = "Gold"
            holder.itemView.diamond_recycler.apply {
                setHasFixedSize(true)
                adapter = goldAdapter
            }
            holder.itemView.view_more_button.setOnClickListener {
                methodCallBack.click(gold)
            }
            goldAdapter.setListener(myContext)
        }
```

**MainFragment**

```
 override fun filterData(myList: MutableList<Item>,type : String) {
     mainFragmentViewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
        mainFragmentViewModel.myFilter(myList,type)
    }
}
```

**MainFragmentViewModel**

```
  private val filterGoldList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Item>>()
  val _filterGold : LiveData<MutableList<Item>>
  get() = filterGoldList

    suspend fun myFilter(myList : MutableList<Item>,type : String) =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
              myList.filter { it.isMainPageItem == true }
                    .let {
                          when(type){
                                "Gold" -> filterGoldList.postValue(it as MutableList<Item>)
                                "Silver" -> filterSilverList.postValue(it as MutableList<Item>)
                          }
                    }
        }
```

I am not able to observe my live data in adapter class. Is there any way to observe live data in adapter class?. Someone please tell me how can i do it. Thanks in advance..

Comment: No, I ain't able to use it in my adapter class. Can you write down any simple solution?

Comment: I think you  must use Flow instead of LiveData 

https://proandroiddev.com/implementing-search-filter-using-kotlin-channels-and-flows-in-your-android-application-df7c96e58b19

Comment: Okay , so how it is possible with flow then ? Can you please  explain with code ..

Comment: If you're willing to use Jetpack Compose, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).

Comment: This resource doesn't help in my issue. I don't wanna use Flow now . I am finding other solution that stick to my current solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843951/15754377

Comment: @VivekGupta Is the link has solution of my question ?

Comment: You asked, how can you observe live data inside adapter class so the link shows one of the way to do it.

Comment: And another possible solution to observe live data inside of the adapter is so pass the viewLifecycleOwner as an argument to adapter constructor.