# Android Studio count Clicks of every item in recyclerview separately

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, counter

I want to count the clicks for each item in my recycler View. In this recycler view there are some sort of contacts. I want that there is a counter (for every item for its own) so that I click for example contact 1 (then contact 1 has one click), then I click on contact 2 and after that I click again on contact 2 (then contact 2 has two clicks) --> but contact 1 has still only 1 click.

and so on.

I already tried it a few times, but the problem is, that when I create the counter and click on the item / cardview then the counter just continues and the second contact has then for example 3 clicks, because the counter just counts the clicks and not the clicks on the cardview / item.

How can I fix this ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<Object> arrContacts = new ArrayList<>();
FloatingActionButton btnOpenDialog;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerContactAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerContact);
    btnOpenDialog = findViewById(R.id.btnOpenDialog);

    btnOpenDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_update_lay);

            EditText edtName = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
            EditText edtNumber = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtNumber);
            Button btnAction = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnAction);

            btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String name = "", number = "";

                    if(!edtName.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        name = edtName.getText().toString();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Contact Name!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    if(!edtNumber.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        number = edtNumber.getText().toString();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Contact Number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    arrContacts.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_24,name, number));
                    adapter.notifyItemInserted(arrContacts.size()-1);
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(arrContacts.size()-1);
                    dialog.dismiss();


                }
            });
                dialog.show();


        }
    });






    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    arrContacts.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_24,"a","1234"));
    arrContacts.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_24,"b","3456"));
    arrContacts.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_24,"c","4567"));
    arrContacts.add(new ContactModel(R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_24,"d","5678"));

    adapter = new RecyclerContactAdapter(this, arrContacts);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



}
```

}

```
public class ContactModel {
int img;
String name, number;
Integer counter;


public ContactModel(int img, String name, String number){
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
    this.img = img;


}

public ContactModel(String name, String number){
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}
```

}

```
public class RecyclerContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerContactAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
ArrayList<Object> arrContacts;


RecyclerContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> arrContacts){
    this.context = context;
    this.arrContacts = arrContacts;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){

    ContactModel model = (ContactModel) arrContacts.get(position);
    holder.imgContact.setImageResource(model.img);
    holder.txtName.setText(model.name);
    holder.txtNumber.setText(model.number);



    holder.IlRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_update_lay);


            EditText edtName = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
            EditText edtNumber = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtNumber);
            Button btnAction = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnAction);
            TextView txtTitle = dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            txtTitle.setText("Update Contact");

            btnAction.setText("Update");

            edtName.setText(((ContactModel) arrContacts.get(position)).name);
            edtNumber.setText(((ContactModel) arrContacts.get(position)).number);


            btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String name="", number="";

                    if(!edtName.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        name = edtName.getText().toString();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Please Enter Contact Name!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    if(!edtNumber.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        number = edtNumber.getText().toString();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Please Enter Contact Number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    arrContacts.set(position, new ContactModel(name, number));
                    notifyItemChanged(position);

                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    holder.IlRow.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Delete Contact").
                    setMessage("Are your sure you want to delete?").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_delete_24)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                arrContacts.remove(position);
                                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        }
                    });

            builder.show();

            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){return arrContacts.size(); }


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName, txtNumber;
    ImageView imgContact;
    LinearLayout IlRow;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
        imgContact = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgContact);
        IlRow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.LLRow);



    }

}
public void onItemClicked(ContactModel contactModel){
    Toast.makeText(context,contactModel.counter,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: where are you updating counter ?

Answer (score 0):

I just made a sample app to show you , how can you do it by using [this](https://jitpack.io/#vivekgupta4Git/AwakeningViewHolderLife) library.
All you have to do is just , add the dependency , extend your viewholder to
LifeAwareViewHolder and then you can extend your adapter to AdapterWithLCViewHolder.

inside onBindViewHolder () method

```
onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position){
             //create viewmodel the way you do , I am showing code in kotlin 
         though.
        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).[ItemViewModel::class.java]
        val item = getItem(position) as DomainClass
        viewModel.count()
        viewModel.countClick.observe(this){ count->
         binding.textview.text = count.toString()
         }
          }
```

where ItemViewModel is

```
class ItemViewModel : ViewModel(){
    var count = 0
    var countClick = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    fun count(){
       ++count
      countClick.value =  count.toString()
    }
```

[link to library](https://jitpack.io/#vivekgupta4Git/AwakeningViewHolderLife)

[here is sample video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1os0__RR0gP1WfagRjti44SNXxljRFQIi/view?usp=sharing)